# How to set the font for Text field hint when selected

Tags: codenameone

I have used text field with hint "Phone Number". When I click on the text field the text "Phone Number" font will be increased automatically. I'm wondering is there any way I can control the size of the font when =text field control is in focus or selected. Please advise.

Code:

```
TextField num = new TextField("", "Phone Number", 10, TextField.PHONENUMBER);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to style both the selected and unselected versions of the UIID in a consistent way. You can do that in the Codename One designer tool by editing the style you overrode and making sure both `Selected` and `Unselected` tabs have the same value for the font.

Comment: Shai.. I haven't defined any UIID for font. I had UIID for text field and it was consistent with Selected and UnSelected. Please let me know if I need to create style UIID for font and set TextUIID for TextField. Please advise.

Comment: Looking at this again I think that what you are seeing is the native text field hint as you switch from lightweight to the native editing. We can't control the size of the text in the native hint but if you define the size of the `TextHint` UIID to be larger it should be closer. You can try setting the theme constant `nativeHintBool` to `false` to hide the native hint altogether